# Split file occupying the same memory space as source file

Tags: file, split, filesystems

I have a file, say 100MB in size. I need to split it into (for example) 4 different parts.
Let's say first file from 0-20MB, second 20-60MB, third 60-70MB and last 70-100MB.
But I do not want to do a safe split - into 4 output files. I would like to do it in place. So the output files should use the same place on the hard disk that is occupied by this one source file, and **literally** split it, without making a copy (so at the moment of split, we should loose the original file).

In other words, the input file *is* the output files.

Is this possible, and if yes, how?

I was thinking maybe to manually add a record to the filesystem, that a file A starts here, and ends here (in the middle of another file), do it 4 times and afterwards remove the original file. But for that I would probably need administrator privileges, and probably wouldn't be safe or healthy for the filesystem.

Programming language doesn't matter, I'm just interested if it would be possible.

Comment: Probably can be done, certainly unwise to do it.

Comment: The reason why I would want to do this madness is performance and disk space. Spliting a file 'the right way', if the file is, say 20GB, would require another 20GB and a lot of time to complete. Splitting 'in-place' would take a split of a second and the result would be the same, especially if I am dealing with less relevant data.

Comment: Unless you break the filesystem, then you get to spend all day fixing it :)

Comment: At the very least, doing this would require your split points to occur on block boundaries.

Comment: True. I would be especially interested in possible ways of implementation in either NTFS or HFS+ (or both).

Comment: @Kevin - good point. But I could deal with that by buffering the excess (data above the block) into memory and adding or substracting that after the split operation is completed. (So I guess it would be a "close to" split with some manual fine-tuning)

Comment: In theory, this is rather simple. In terms of inodes (NTFS: file records, HFS+: ??), the first inode contains the filesize and the (beginning of the) list of blocks that belong to the file. Ideally you would just change 4 inodes. But I doubt you'll get away with it that easy. You need closer looks at the NTFS and HFS+ internals.

Comment: It's possible to split a large file conventionally without using extra space equal to the entire file. You can copy the *last* chunk to a new file, then use `truncate()` to remove that part from the input file, and repeat. The input file ends up as the chunk at the beginning. This only takes extra space equal to the size of a chunk. Uses almost as much time as the naive approach, but less space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea is not so mad as some comments paint it. It would certainly be possible to have a file system API that supports such reinterpreting operations (to be sure, the desired split is probably not exacly aligned to block boundaries, but you could reallocate just those few boundary blocks and still save a lot of temporary space).

None of the common file system abstraction layers support this; but recall that they don't even support something as reasonable as "insert mode" (which would rewrite only one or two blocks when you insert something into the middle of a file, instead of all blocks), only an overwrite and an append mode. The reasons for that are largely historical, but the current model is so entrenched that it is unlikely a richer API will become common any time soon.

Comment: Thanks! I initially thought the same, the world is built on crazy ideas :) I think some proprietary implementations allow such split operations, such as hardware video recorders (PVRs). A lot of them support splitting recorded video files, an action performed on huge HD files which takes only a couple of seconds. It's a shame there's no API for such an operation :( I'd give you a +1 but I don't have +15 reputation yet.

Answer (score 1):

As I explain in [this question](https://superuser.com/a/421756/84556) on SuperUser, you can achieve this using the technique outlined by Tom Zych in his comment.

```
bigfile="mybigfile-100Mb"
chunkprefix="chunk_"
# Chunk offsets
OneMegabyte=1048576
chunkoffsets=(0 $((OneMegabyte*20)) $((OneMegabyte*60)) $((OneMegabyte*70)))

currentchunk=$((${#chunkoffsets[@]}-1))
while [ $currentchunk -ge 0 ]; do
    # Print current chunk number, so we know it is still running.
    echo -n "$currentchunk "
    offset=${chunkoffsets[$currentchunk]}
    # Copy end of $archive to new file
    tail -c +$((offset+1)) "$bigfile" > "$chunkprefix$currentchunk"
    # Chop end of $archive
    truncate -s $offset "$archive"
    currentchunk=$((currentchunk-1))
done
```

You need to give the script the starting position (offset in bytes, zero means a chunk starting at `bigfile`'s first byte) of each chunk, in ascending order, like on the fifth line.

If necessary, automate it using seq : The following command will give a chunkoffsets with one chunk at 0, then one starting at 100k, then one for every megabyte for the range 1--10Mb, (note the -1 for the `last` parameter, so it is excluded) then one chunk every two megabytes for the range 10--20Mb.

```
OneKilobyte=1024
OneMegabyte=$((1024*OneKilobyte))
chunkoffsets=(0 $((100*OneKilobyte)) $(seq $OneMegabyte $OneMegabyte $((10*OneMegabyte-1))) $(seq $((10*OneMegabyte-1)) $((2*OneMegabyte)) $((20*OneMegabyte-1))))
```

To see which chunks you have set :

```
for offset in "${chunkoffsets[@]}"; do echo "$offset"; done
0
102400
1048576
2097152
3145728
4194304
5242880
6291456
7340032
8388608
9437184
10485759
12582911
14680063
16777215
18874367
20971519
```

This technique has the drawback that it needs at least the size of the largest chunk available (you can mitigate that by making smaller chunks, and concatenating them somewhere else, though). Also, it will copy all the data, so it's nowhere near instant.

As to the fact that some hardware video recorders (PVRs) manage to split videos within seconds, they probably only store a list of offsets for each video (a.k.a. chapters), and display these as independent videos in their user interface.